# Python Weighted DiGraph Visualization

Tags: python, graph, visualization, networkx

I'm trying to visualize markov style state diagrams.

I've tried using pygraphviz via both direct dot language and networkx.

I've tried using pyplot within matplotlib.

In both cases the outcome is ugly. In pyplot the arrows are just thicker lines, and in pygraphviz the labeled lines aren't arranged well.

Personally I prefer the networkx->pygraphviz option. Here's a brief code snippet that illustrates my question.

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(0,1,weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(2,3,weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(3,4,weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(1,0,weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(2,1,weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(3,2,weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(4,3,weight=0.5)

for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True):
    d['label'] = d.get('weight','')

A = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)
A.layout(prog='dot')
A.draw('test.png')
```

Which produces
[ugly graph labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8YcP.png)

In reality I want something like this
[better graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wwz3.jpg)

Or even better yet something like this [pretty transition diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtqkc.png)

I would have embedded the photos, but I'm not yet allowed. :(

Thanks!

Comment: so what is the question exactly?

Comment: asker wants the graph horizontally as in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wwz3.jpg)

Comment: Well mostly I want the arrows and labels to be arranged more cleanly. Currently they nearly overlap, and it makes the diagram hard to read.

Comment: have you tried gephi? It has beautiful displays.

Comment: @rogdor I will give it a go and report back! Thanks.